# Entity Framework - Compute Average With HasFieldGenerator

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core

My current issue is with a storefront API. I have a one->many relationship for products and reviews. I'm trying to compute the average review score on table update with the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ProductReviews>()     
  .Property(s => s.AverageScore)     
  .ValueGeneratedOnAddOrUpdate()     
  .HasValueGenerator<ReviewAverageGenerator>();
```

Using the entity:

```
...
public class ProductReviews : BaseEntity 
{          
  public string Reviewer { get; set; }          
  public string ReviewDescription { get; set; }      
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]     
  public double AverageScore { get; private set; }     
  public int ReviewRating { get; set; }          
  public int ReviewVotes { get; set; }      
  public int ProductId { get; set; }     
 }
```

The ReviewAverageGenerator class is as follows

```
public override double Next(EntityEntry entry) 
{     
double avgScore;
var reviewAvg = _context.ProductReviews 
  .Where(x => x.ProductId == ??????)
   .GroupBy(x => x.ProductId)
  .?????;
  ...
return avgScore; //ProductReviews.Scores / reviewAvg.Count()
}
```

I'm having trouble figuring out how to aggregate the individual scores, since I'm not sure how to access that with the query. I'm not even sure if this is the right approach. Any help would be appreciated.